Algebraic Equation with multiple variables.
A lot of times I have multiple equations, and I don't have to completely solve them, rather just transform them into a particular form and get its value. For that I need algebraic manipulations and patterns. Despite having basic math knowledge, I often don't understand how to proceed in such question.
For example, I have a following system of equations
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a^2}{2^2-1^2}+
\frac{b^2}{2^2-3^2}+
\frac{c^2}{2^2-5^2}+
\frac{d^2}{2^2-7^2}
&=\\ \frac{a^2}{4^2-1^2}+
\frac{b^2}{4^2-3^2}+
\frac{c^2}{4^2-5^2}+
\frac{d^2}{4^2-7^2}
&=\\ \frac{a^2}{6^2-1^2}+
\frac{b^2}{6^2-3^2}+
\frac{c^2}{6^2-5^2}+
\frac{d^2}{6^2-7^2} 
&=\\ \frac{a^2}{8^2-1^2}+
\frac{b^2}{8^2-3^2}+
\frac{c^2}{8^2-5^2}+
\frac{d^2}{8^2-7^2} 
&= 1
\end{align*}$$
And $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = P^2$, then find $P$.
Yes, it can be solved by assuming $\alpha=a^2$, $\beta=b^2$, $\gamma=c^2$ and $\delta=d^2$ and then solving the system of equations by matrix or some other method.
However, there seems to be a pattern in the denominator of equations: there's $2^2$ then $4^2$, $6^2$, $8^2$, and all are subtracted with $1^2,3^2,5^2,7^2$. So I think there might be something like cyclic equation or symmetry that might just help to solve equations more easily. Thanks.

Replacing $2,4,6,8$ by a general $x$, and clearing denominators:
$$(x-1)(x-9)(x-25)(x-49)=\alpha(x-9)(x-25)(x-49)+\beta(x-1)(x-25)(x-49)+\gamma(x-1)(x-9)(x-49)+\delta(x-1)(x-9)(x-25)$$
And what we are given is that, this is true when $x=2^2,4^2,6^2,8^2$. The above (take RHS to the LHS) can be written as $f(x)=0$, where $f$ is a monic degree-$4$ equation. Thus, it must be that
$$(x-1)(x-9)(x-25)(x-49)-\alpha(x-9)(x-25)(x-49)-\beta(x-1)(x-25)(x-49)-\gamma(x-1)(x-9)(x-49)-\delta(x-1)(x-9)(x-25)=(x-2^2)(x-4^2)(x-6^2)(x-8^2)$$
Compare the coefficients of $x^3$.

Edit: The point is
$$f(x)=(x-1)(x-9)(x-25)(x-49)-\alpha(x-9)(x-25)(x-49)-\beta(x-1)(x-25)(x-49)-\gamma(x-1)(x-9)(x-49)-\delta(x-1)(x-9)(x-25)$$
is a degree $4$ polynomial and has leading coefficient $1$. But it has roots $2^2,4^2,6^2,8^2$. A polynomial of $n$ degree is determined by its $n$ roots, and its leading coefficient. In our case,
$$f(x)=1(x-2^2)(x-4^2)(x-6^2)(x-8^2)$$
Now, compare the coefficients of $x^3$. On RHS, we get $-(2^2+4^2+6^2+8^2)=-120$. On LHS, we get $-(1+9+25+49)-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta)$. That should give you the value of $P$.
Hope this helps. :>

Thank you for answer. I had two doubts please clarify 1  in the last step i thought RHS=0, but it's like (x-2²)(x-4²)(x-6²)(x-8²)  is it because 2,4,6,8 are roots of the equation, still then it's bit unclear. 2. How do you go about comparing x³ coefficients it would be great if you provided brief idea or starting point to do that  Thanks a lot.

@OmkarDeshmukh: I made some edits.

This is reminiscent of an old AIME question which used to the same technique.

@Sahaj Can you share that question?

@OmkarDeshmukh AIME 1984 Problem 15
